# Image view not clipped inside constraint layout with drawable shape background

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout

This is my drawable shape

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    >
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:topRightRadius="20dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="60dp"/>
<solid android:color="@color/primary_blue"/>


</shape>
```

My layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="296dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:clipChildren="true"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_shape_bottom_right_curved"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    android:outlineProvider="background"
    android:layout_height="198dp">

   <ImageView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:src="@drawable/phase_banner"
      android:scaleType="centerCrop"
      android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The image keeps on being square and not getting the shape of drawable. Please help

When i add shape to the layout its showing the shape . But when i set image src its showing sqaure image , when setting background, it getting into right shape. But i need to load image from glide  . so i need to make it work with src

Comment: Can you post the code for bg_shape_bottom_right_curved?

Comment: you have to make ImageView rectangle ?

Comment: @Cheticamp thats is the drawable shape code i have given

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, your background drawable does not qualify for clipping. From [Clip Views](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping#Clip):

> Only rectangle, circle, and round rectangle outlines support clipping, as determined by the Outline.canClip() method.

Your background drawable does not qualify as a rounded rectangle but is implemented internally as a path (I believe). This is one reason clipping is failing for you.

Let's create a simple rounded rectangle drawable:

**simple_rounded_rectangle.bg**

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle" >  
    <corners android:radius="30dp"/>  
    <solid android:color="@color/primary_blue"/>  
</shape>
```

Also, let's modify the layout a little:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout 
      android:id="@+id/layout"  
      android:layout_width="400dp"  
      android:layout_height="198dp"  
      android:background="@drawable/simple_rounded_rectangle"  
      android:outlineProvider="background">  
  
  <ImageView  
      android:id="@+id/imageView"  
      android:layout_width="match_parent"  
      android:layout_height="match_parent"  
      android:adjustViewBounds="true"  
      android:scaleType="centerCrop"  
      android:src="@drawable/phase_banner" />  
</LinearLayout>
```

We will also need to add some code to direct the view system to clip the view to the outline:

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {  
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)  
        val layout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.layout)  
        layout.clipToOutline = true  
  }  
}
```

The main thing in this code is the line

```
layout.clipToOutline = true
```

which indicates that clipping should occur. There should be an XML attribute that does the same thing `android:clipToOutline` but there isn't below API 31. See the [android:clipToOutline bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37036728).

Putting it altogether we see the following. (The image is one I supplied.)

[image]

If you use your drawable for the background, it will not be clipped for the reason I mentioned above.

You will need to fall back to a different method of clipping if you need asymmetric corners on your drawable. You may want to look at applications of [clipPath](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#clipPath(android.graphics.Path)). You will find information on how to do this if you do some online searching. I also suggest the Medium post [Clipping and shadows on Android](https://medium.com/@Zielony/clipping-and-shadows-on-android-e702a0d96bd4) for other alternatives.

Take a look at the [Material Components Library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android). *MaterialCardView* and *ShapeableImageView* may be useful.

Comment: yea you are right . i did that by refering Google mdc doc,

Answer (score 0):

This is your drawable shape.

```
     <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:topRightRadius="20dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="20dp" 
 />
<solid android:color="@color/primary_blue"/>
</shape>
```

**Layout**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:clipChildren="true"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    android:outlineProvider="background"
    android:layout_height="198dp">
   <ImageView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@drawable/phase_banner"
      android:src="@drawable/XYZ"
      android:scaleType="centerCrop"
      android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Try this you want like this?

Answer (score 0):

For me it didn't work until I changed

```
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

to fixed sizes

```
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
```

Or until I've set `scaleType`

```
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

And then my code in fragment clipped successfully

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    binding.imageView.clipToOutline = true
    binding.imageView.setImageBitmap(finalBitmap)
}
```